# I'm trying to find an algorithm for merging m sorted lists (of total n elements) in n log2 m runtme

Tags: algorithm

Above says it all. I cannot really think of a way to do this, and how to prove it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Put the input lists in a heap (aka a priority queue) where each list's priority is its first element.  To get the next element of the output list, pull the top list off the heap, append its first element to the output list, remove that element from the input list, and (if the input list is not empty) put the input list back in the heap.  Repeat until the heap is empty.

See [this question and answer on Computer Science stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12853/heap-give-an-on-lg-k-time-algorithm-to-merge-k-sorted-lists-into-one-so) for more details.